# Select previous user input using scanner

Tags: java, input

I'm testing some code which users select numbers 0 & 1 - 3. 1 - 3 selects an option and adds the a number to the total, and 0 exits and prints the final total. The code seems to work but only in order eg: type 1,2,3,0. My question is how can I make it so that the user can enter any selection at any point eg: 2,2,3,0 and then print final total.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Coffee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double AmericanPrice;
        double EspressoPrice;
        double LattePrice;

        double totalBill;

        AmericanPrice = 1.99;
        EspressoPrice = 2.50;
        LattePrice = 2.15;

        int selectionBill;
        int selectionA;
        int selectionE;
        int selectionL;

        selectionBill = 0;
        selectionA = 1;
        selectionE = 2;
        selectionL = 3;

        totalBill = 0.0;

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) { 
            System.out.print("Place your order: ");

            if(user.nextInt() == selectionA) {
                totalBill = totalBill + AmericanPrice;
                System.out.print("Place your order: ");
            }

            if(user.nextInt() == selectionE) {
                totalBill = totalBill + EspressoPrice;
                System.out.print("Place your order: ");
            }

            if(user.nextInt() == selectionL) {
                totalBill = totalBill + LattePrice;
                System.out.print("Place your order: ");
            }

            if(user.nextInt() == selectionBill) {
                System.out.print("Total: "+totalBill);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you call nextInt(), you get the next int. So, if you call it twice, you read two ints. Call nextInt() only once at each iteration. Store the result in a variable.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure that I follow. I understand the first part of the comment but not the last. I tell the scanner that _if_ the next line is 1,2,3 then add to total but only print final total _if_ 0 is entered. So why doesn't it allow me to enter 1,2,3,3 or 2,2,3,1?

Comment: Read Martin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JB said, calling nextInt() actually "consumes" the input, so calling it again get the next one. What you want is to call it once then compare, and repeat in a loop, something like:

```
int answer = user.nextInt();
while(answer != 0) {
  if(answer == selectionA) {
    ...
  }
  if(answer == selectionB) {
    ...
  }
  answer = user.nextInt();
}
```

Note that a "[switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)" maybe a better option than ifs here.

Comment: Ah yes switch would be a better option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Martin and JB are both correct, switch could work fine. There is no need to use an if loop, only while could work well here.

```
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Place your order: ");
int answer = user.nextInt();
while(answer !=0)
{
    totalBill = answer + totalBill;
    System.out.println("Place your order: ");
    answer = user.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Total: " + totalBill);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in the code:

```
//creating infinite loop
while(true) {

    //every time we're returing to the begining of the loop we're asking about the order.
    System.out.print("Place your order: ");  

    //here we're hanging the execution of the program to wait for users input. If the users input is not equal to selection A we're not doing anything. So if you input i.e 3, you will go exactly to...
    if(user.nextInt() == selectionA) {  
        totalBill = totalBill + AmericanPrice;
        System.out.print("Place your order: ");
    }

    //...here. And here you again wait for the input. If it's not 2 you'll go further without writing anything to the user. And not adding to the bill.
    if(user.nextInt() == selectionE) {
        totalBill = totalBill + EspressoPrice;
        System.out.print("Place your order: ");
    }
    //... and so on.
}
```

So what you would like to do is first take the input - whatever it is, and then compare it to all of the possibilities.

Like that:

```
while(true) { 

    System.out.print("Place your order: ");

    int orderId = user.nextInt();

    if(orderId == selectionA) {
        totalBill = totalBill + AmericanPrice;
    } else if(orderId == selectionE) {
        totalBill = totalBill + EspressoPrice;
    } else if(orderId == selectionL) {
        totalBill = totalBill + LattePrice;
    } else if(orderId == selectionBill) {
        System.out.print("Total: "+ totalBill);
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of all this `if-else` statements you could use `switch statement` which is a little more elegant.